# Trello API authentication popup not closed

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, trello

I'm trying to demonstrate the Trello API but i'm having issues with the authentication procedure.

```
var ConnectToTrello = function () {
//console.log("Authenticating");
Trello.authorize({
    type: 'popup',
    name: 'Outlook Trello Add-In',
    scope: { read: true, write: true, account: true },
    success: authenticationSuccess,
    error: authenticationError
});};
```

This opens a popup where I can do the authentication, then I get redirected (in the popup) to *https://trello.com/1/token/approve* and nothing happens. The popup is not closing.

Any help would be appreciated.

download [the code here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B715E2BC3D00A40C!874085&authkey=!AMwyd0USglqKHb4&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: What's the body of `authenticationSuccess` and `authenticationError`?

Comment: var authenticationSuccess = function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $('#btnAuthenticate').hide();

}

var authenticationError = function (error) {
    console.log(error);
   

}

Comment: I added the source code [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B715E2BC3D00A40C!874085&authkey=!AMwyd0USglqKHb4&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: @Web_Designer did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: I'm facing this same issue. Any success?

Comment: Any luck with the issue? I have the same problem with react wrapper for client js.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until I tried running the ConnectToTrello function from a button. If you create a simple page with that javascript snippet being executed in the `<script>` block it exhibits the behaviour you describe.

However, if you add a simple button with that function as the onclick event handler, then it works just fine.

```
<button onclick="ConnectToTrello();">press me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the tab not closing in certain browsers while using `type: 'popup'`. Are you able to use `type: 'redirect'` instead? I've had more success with that method.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use redirect.

Comment: I have the same problem and changing to use redirect over popup didn't help me

Comment: Stuck with the same problem ... any help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured out that was because I'm trying to authorize from a `file://` URL. 
Then I hosted the same URL via HTTP Preview via eclipse and it started working as expected.

Note: I also go the token that was expected from this Trello.authorize call.